# How to loop through dict of list of dict kind of data using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration, jira

i am trying to loop through using python

```
{u'customfield_10067': [u'{"field_type":"cmdb-object-cftype","value":{"workspaceId":"dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603","name":"test","objectId":"14","id":"dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603:14"}}']}
```

to get value of custom field in a dict as

```
{
customfield_10067 : 
{"workspaceId":"dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603","objectId":"14","id":"dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603:14"}
}
```

i tried looping as list of dict and dict iteration , however when i loop as a dict it throws error

```
TypeError: ValueError('dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required',) is not JSON serializable
```

when looping as list of dict
it throws string indices error

any help is much appreciated.

```
custom_fields = [] regex = '[^A-Za-z0-9]+' project_id = request.data['project_id'] description = re.sub(regex, ' ', str(request.data['description'])) summary = re.sub(regex, ' ', str(request.data['subject'])) issue_type_id = re.sub(regex, '', str(request.data['issuetype'])) request_dict = dict(request.data)

for fields,value in request_dict.items(): if "custom" in fields: custom_data = {fields : value} custom_fields.append(custom_data) # print(custom_fields) for k,v in dict(custom_fields).items(): print(k) print(v)
```

Comment: Hi abhinav! Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you be able to share your code?

Comment: custom_fields = []
            regex = '[^A-Za-z0-9]+'
            project_id = request.data['project_id']
            description = re.sub(regex, ' ', str(request.data['description']))
            summary = re.sub(regex, ' ', str(request.data['subject']))
            issue_type_id = re.sub(regex, '', str(request.data['issuetype']))
            request_dict = dict(request.data)

Comment: for fields,value in request_dict.items():
                if "custom" in fields:
                    custom_data = {fields : value}
                    custom_fields.append(custom_data)
            # print(custom_fields)
            for k,v in dict(custom_fields).items():
                print(k)
                print(v)

Comment: uh not here. into your question!

Comment: also what is `request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `eval()` will be able to get the work done, though it may need more validations depending on how many strings does your list contain, but you get the idea.

```
dict_list = {u'customfield_10067': [u'{"field_type":"cmdb-object-cftype","value":{"workspaceId":"dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603","name":"test","objectId":"14","id":"dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603:14"}}']}
new_dict = {}
for key, value in dict_list.items():
    new_dict[key] = eval(value[0])['value']
print(new_dict)
```

output:

```
{'customfield_10067': {'workspaceId': 'dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603', 'name': 'test', 'objectId': '14', 'id': 'dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603:14'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bob = {
    "customfield_10067": {
        "workspaceId": "dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603",
        "objectId": "14",
        "id": "dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603:14"
    }
}

customfield_10067 = bob["customfield_10067"]
print(customfield_10067)
```

where bob is name of your table
or you can walk through every element

```
bob = {
    "customfield_10067": {
        "workspaceId": "dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603",
        "objectId": "14",
        "id": "dsjahdjasf-61f7-4421-9ced-df122a122d603:14"
    }
}

for key, value in bob.items:
    for k, v in value.items():
       print(k, v)
```

try it. or you can use modules.